# Opening MySQL.Data source from Github source

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I am trying to build the source for the .net connector c# in Visual Studio 2017. I've tried downloading several versions of the MySQL connector from GitHub (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/releases), but every version has an issue, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I tried downloading the latest version 7.0.7-m6 but this throws an error about inconsistent targeting frameworks for a UAP project. I couldn't find anything about what that means so I tried one of the previous versions, 6.10.1 and 6.10.0 but both of these have different problems.

The error I'm getting back is

```
Source file 'Desktop\mysql-connector-net-6.10.0\Source\MySQL.Data\X\XDevAPI\Common\ColumnTypes.cs' could not be found.
```

There's tonnes of these types of errors, looking at the directory, these files don't exist, yet the project is still referencing them.

I would have thought importing a project from a GitHub release would just work and a release definetely wouldn't have files references that don't exist, so what am I missing.

Comment: _MySqlClient.sln must be compiled with VS 2008, VS 2010, or VS 2012. Also, depending on the version, the dependencies to build it include Visual Studio SDK, NUnit, Entity Framework, and ANTLR Integration for Visual Studio._  As [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation-source.html) say

Comment: That's a little odd, normally if I open a older VS solution to a new VS it asks to upgrade but it didn't. And as I was only worked on in March of this year, seems strange that the requirement to use Visual Studio from 5+ years ago!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isnt it possible to use the nuget for mysql?
The below 6.9.9 compiled at my VS2013
I have removed the tests and EF from projects.

[mysql 6.9.9 google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByrGVa9RXBZAQVVlZkpfS0xVaGM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes you can, but that's not what I want to do, I want to be able to build the source so I can then follow the code through with what's it doing

Comment: 6.6.9 worked in Visual Studio 2017 as well. Seems strange you have to go back that far to get working copy!